# Web push notification action click not opening URL when Chrome is in background in Android 13

Tags: javascript, android, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

We have a service-worker waiting for the 'notificationclick' event, that works fine in desktop/mobile, except in Android 13, if Chrome is in the background.

We send a push with buttons that contain an url, and when one of them is clicked, it doesnt open the tab. If chrome is open, it works correctly, the service worker is running fine because we have statistics logging and they are being sent.

So, this is part of the code running in service-worker.js

```js
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', async function(event) {
const log = new Log(TAG);
  log.setLogLevel(LogLevel.DEBUG);

  log.d('On notification click: ', event.notification).writeLog();
  const data = event.notification.data;
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
    type: 'window',
  }).then(function(clientList) {
    for (let i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
      const client = clientList[i];
      if (client.url === '/' && 'focus' in client) {
        return client.focus();
      }
    }
    if (clients.openWindow) {
      if (event.action == 'action-1') {
        if (data.buttonTopics && data.buttonTopics[0]) topicsSubscribeNotification(data.appKey, data.deviceId, data.buttonTopics[0]);
        return clients.openWindow(data.actions[0]);
      } else if (event.action == 'action-2') {
        if (data.buttonTopics && data.buttonTopics[1]) topicsSubscribeNotification(data.appKey, data.deviceId, data.buttonTopics[1]);
        return clients.openWindow(data.actions[1]);
      } else {
        if (data.topics) topicsSubscribeNotification(data.appKey, data.deviceId, data.topics);
        return clients.openWindow(data.url);
      }
    }
  }));
  event.preventDefault();
  // send statistics to our api
});
```

We tried simpler code to open urls and the problems persists in Android 13 devices when chrome is in the background, it works properly in older Android versions, and in desktop, and in Android 13 when its in the foreground.